# Skin issues with multiple controls in a Dot Net Nuke module

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5, dotnetnuke-module

In the Dot Net Nuke module that I'm developing I need to separate the controls into several different areas.  Unfortunately, it appears that Dot Net Nuke thinks that any control identified by a control key is an 'edit' screen and changes the skin automatically.

- Is it possible to change this behaviour programmatically?
- What is the best method of switching controls without having the skin changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a topic that folks have a lot of difficulty understanding and working around.  For starters, see [my blog post on module isolation](http://weblogs.asp.net/briandukes/archive/2009/01/21/understanding-module-isolation-in-dnn.aspx).

The short story is that you'll get module isolation (which includes switching to the edit skin) whenever you use a control key in the URL to change controls.  If you don't want that behavior, you'll have to work around it.

There are a number of established techniques, from simple do-it-yourself to more complex arrangements.  In my blog post, I point you to [Michael Washington's navigation tutorial](http://adefwebserver.com/dotnetnukehelp/Misc/ModuleNavigationOptions.htm),  which includes using a [`PlaceHolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder.aspx) and loading controls dynamically into that, using a [`MultiView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.multiview.aspx) control, or using multiple module definitions (which is a whole other paradigm).